# How to fix if else output in terms of assigning NAs to unknown

Tags: r, if-statement, missing-data

I'm trying to assign my NAs to "unknown" in my dataset by doing the following code.

```
str(df$Var)
Factor w/ 4 levels "Current smoker",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 

df$Var<- ifelse(is.na(df$Var),"unknown",df$Var)
```

After I ran the code the string was changed

```
str(df$Var
chr [1:100] "unknown" "1" "1"
```

Is there a way that I can assign the NAs to "unknown" without changing my variables names to "1", "2", "3"

I hope that my question is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the function : `as.character()` on your data frame's column.

`df$Var <- as.character(df$Var)`

Example :

```
factors <- as.factor(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, 40, "Allo"))`
factors <- as.character(factors)
factors <- ifelse(is.na(factors),"unknown",factors)
```

Output :

```
"unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "100"     "40"      "Allo"
```

The reason why you're getting `1, 2, 3, etc` is because you have factors, you should convert them to `characters` before applying the function.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for converting this values, sans ifelse(), is using

`factors$Var[is.na(factors$Var)] <- "unknown"`

You will still need to covert the variable to a character. R assigns numeric values to factor levels, and therefore a straight conversion will turn those levels into the associated numeric value rather than the numeric value.

Example:

```
factors <- data.frame(Id = seq(1,7), 
                        Var = as.factor(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 100, 40, "Allo")))

factors$Var <- as.character(factors$Var)

factors$Var[is.na(factors$Var)] <- "unknown"
```

With the output of the data frame looking like:

```
  Id     Var
1  1 unknown
2  2 unknown
3  3 unknown
4  4 unknown
5  5     100
6  6      40
7  7    Allo
```